# Rails custom route does not map correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I´m making an ajax request to another controller but having problem with the routing. This is my request: (using react.js)

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'allRooms',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                this.setState({data:data});
            }.bind(this)
        });
```

I´ve put this in my routes.rb:

```
  get 'allRooms', to: 'rooms#allRooms'
```

Now, `allRooms` is an method I defined inside my `rooms_controller`

However, the request gets this url when trigged: `http://localhost:3000/houses/allRooms`

The call is made from the show-view of my house-controller.

Why does not my request route properly to the rooms-controller? (I´ve restarted rails server multiple times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing your js code as:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/allRooms',
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(data){
    this.setState({data:data});
  }.bind(this)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/allRooms',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                this.setState({data:data});
            }.bind(this)
        });
```

Comment: One way is to assign url to global configuration, and just use it when invokking request

for example, you may attach to `window.App.Configuration.Urls.AllRoomsUrl = "#{all_rooms_url}"` when the page is being generated

and then when invoking ajax call, read it via `window.App.Configuration.Urls.AllRoomsUrl`